# What incentives does a high-income group need to let go of a portion of their income?

Tags: economy, inequality, poverty

I am doing research, and my question is: **What incentives does a high-income group need to let go of a portion of their income?**

My idea, which I haven't found sources for, is that rich people could sustain a poor/homeless person and then claim them as dependents on their taxes to get a tax break. This would require a tax reform to allow non-relatives to be claimed as dependents in the U.S.

Could this help close the gap?

Comment: If you search Google Scholar for research on donations to the homeless, you'll find a lot. Once you do some preliminary research hopefully this question can be refined to something clear and answerable.

Comment: I wonder whether this question might be better suited to the economics SE. May also be useful to look into a universal basic income - sounds similar to what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

The only incentive that a high-income group need to let go of a portion of their income is a moral standard for the society. Take, for example, the Islamic system, where one of [its fundamental pillars is Zakat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat)

A similar system of tithing existed among Christians, and even a communal system of living existed among [the early Christians as mentioned in the Book of Acts](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202&version=NIV).

These moral systems have worked for centuries prior to the Industrial Revolution and are still working in the Middle East with a great deal of success.